# Maximize $\mathrm{tr}(A^TX)$ subject to $||A||_2\leq 1$

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization

> Given $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$. Denote $||A||_2$ as spectral norm of matrix $A$. Find
>
> \begin{array}{ll}\sup\limits_{{A:\,||A||_2\leq 1\\}} \mathrm{tr}(A^TX).\end{array}

---

My attempt: Using SVD, we have $A=U_1\Sigma_1V_1^*$ and $X=U_2\Sigma_2V_2^*$.

$\mathrm{tr}(A^TX)=\mathrm{tr}(V_1\Sigma_1^TU_1^*U_2\Sigma_2V_2^*)=\mathrm{tr}(\Sigma_1^TU_1^*U_2\Sigma_2V_2^*V_1)\leq \mathrm{tr}(I_{n\times m}U_1^*U_2\Sigma_2V_2^*V_1)\leq\mathrm{tr}(I_{n\times m}\Sigma_2).$

First inequality because all the singular values of $A$ are less than or equal to $1$. Not sure if the second inequality is correct, I have a feeling that if we multiply diagonal matrix by unitary matrix, the diagonal numbers will be spread to off-diagonal side and trace becomes less.

Comment: Like you say, put $X = U\Sigma V^*$, then
$ \text{tr}(A^T X) = \text{tr}(A^T U\Sigma V^*) = \text{tr}(V^* A^T U \Sigma) = \text{tr}(B^T \Sigma)$, where $B = U^T A (V^*)^T$. Notice that $\lVert A\rVert_2 = \lVert B\rVert_2$. The effect of this is we may replace $X$ by $\Sigma$. Can you answer the question when $X$ is diagonal?

Comment: @vujazzman, thank! I got the point.